# Sending rolling statistics to RNN

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, rnn, feature-engineering, gru

I'm curious if anyone has seen cases where sending rolling statistics such as mean, median, min, max, standard deviation, skewness, kurtosis, etc. have been helpful for model accuracy?

If so please respond with your use case and which rolling statistics you found the most helpful.

Thank you